# Modify a pictogram element in Eclipse RCP Graphiti

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

I tried the solution provided here:
 [automatic update of graphiti diagrams in case of changes in the datamodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592810/automatic-update-of-graphiti-diagrams-in-case-of-changes-in-the-datamodel)

I am trying to call the Upadate feature in the UpdateNeeded function of my class which implements AbstractUpdateFeature:

```java
TransactionalEditingDomain domain = TransactionUtils.getEditingDomain(diagram);
domain.getCommandStack().execute(new RecordingCommand(domain) {
public void doExecute() {
  UpdateContext updateContext = new                                                                         
  UpdateContext(getDiagram().getChildren().get(0).                                                                             getGraphicsAlgorithm().getPictogramElement(  ));
  IUpdateFeature updateFeature = getFeatureProvider().getUpdateFeature(updateContext);
  updateFeature.update(updateContext);
}});
```

In the Update function I am trying to change the value of the text field of a Pictogram element:

```java
    // Set name in pictogram model
    if (pictogramElement instanceof ContainerShape) {
        ContainerShape cs = (ContainerShape) pictogramElement;
        for (Shape shape : cs.getChildren()) {
            if (shape.getGraphicsAlgorithm() instanceof Text) {
                Text text = (Text) shape.getGraphicsAlgorithm(); 
                text.setValue("aaa");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot modify resource set without a write transaction
at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionChangeRecorder.assertWriting(TransactionChangeRecorder.java:348)
at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionChangeRecorder.appendNotification(TransactionChangeRecorder.java:302)
at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionChangeRecorder.processObjectNotification(TransactionChangeRecorder.java:284)
at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionChangeRecorder.notifyChanged(TransactionChangeRecorder.java:240)
```

Comment: What exception? Show your code and the error. We are not clairvoyant.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have modified my question with the required information.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the feature using DiagramBehavior

```
getDiagramBehavior().executeFeature(feature, context);
```